# Why move the key.snk file to the Properties folder in Sharepoint projects?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, strongname, snk, strong-named-key

It is "de rigeuer" here to move the key.snk file generated when a new project is created from its default location at the bottom of the Solution up into the Properties folder.

This is not just a local "superstition"; it seems to be the "accepted method", as seen [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=DgkdRs8bnaEC&pg=PT2694&lpg=PT2694&dq=sharepoint%20key.snk%20file%20properties%20folder&source=bl&ots=X2LEQdrJ48&sig=pNhQMrNrfmL5amOPUaw4dtpQTf0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RLFLVZqUHYrHogSl6oGgDQ&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=sharepoint%20key.snk%20file%20properties%20folder&f=false)

But why? That book does not seem to explain the raison d'etre for this action...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no difference where the key file is located as long as the assembly is signed.

The author explains **why she/he does that**:

"As projects become more complex, a lack of vertical space in the Solution Explorer makes projects more difficult to work with"

So the reason seems to be to hide the key file inside the properties folder to save some space on the visual studio Solution Explorer display.

My personal opinion is to ignore that as that will confuse another developer which is expecting to see it in the default location: in the project root.

Comment: By the way I like your use of French in the post, it gives it a classy feel :)

Comment: I actually don't know French (except those phrases commonly used among us Yankees); I do know German and Spanish, though.